# Why do I get , at the beginning of my html output using map and ES6 templating

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

map returns an array but

I get this

```
,
a
b
```

instead of expected

```
a,
b,
```

```js
let names = ["a", "b"];
template = `<table>
          ${names.map(name => `<TR><TD>${name}</TD></TR>`)}
          </table>
          `
let div = document.getElementById("container");
div.innerHTML = template;
```

```html
<div id="container">
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `map` returns an array, and the templating converts it to a string, which means you get the array entries with commas between them. So the result is:

```html
<TR><TD>a</TD></TR>,
<TR><TD>b</TD></TR>
```

Note that

1. There's only one comma (you said you were expecting two, but `Array#toString` calls `Array#join` which only puts commas *between* elements, not at the beginning or end).
2. The comma is **between** the rows (which is invalid markup). When you do that, it's up to the browser how best to handle it. Some handle it by collecting all of the invalid markup and putting it before the table. Others by putting it after the table. If you're seeing the comma before the table, you're using a browser that does the former (like Chrome).

Static example:

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <TR><TD>a</TD></TR>,
    <TR><TD>b</TD></TR>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Bottom-line: Use `.join("")` to get rid of the commas entirely:

```js
let names = ["a", "b"];
template = `<table>
          ${names.map(name => `<TR><TD>${name}</TD></TR>`).join("")}
          </table>
          `
let div = document.getElementById("container");
div.innerHTML = template;
```

```html
<div id="container">
</div>
```

...or if you **want** commas after the entries, insert them manually in the template:

```js
let names = ["a", "b"];
template = `<table>
          ${names.map(name => `<TR><TD>${name},</TD></TR>`).join("")}
          </table>
          `
let div = document.getElementById("container");
div.innerHTML = template;
```

```html
<div id="container">
</div>
```

Comment: precisely if it returns an array I should have a,b, and not ,ab: that's my question

Comment: @user310291: I covered that in my two bullet points above...?

Comment: @t-j-crowder so it's this stupid browser behavior that I didn't know!

Answer (score 1):

`map` is likely not what you're looking for, `reduce` is the correct method in this case (map returns an array, you want a string).

```
let names = ['a', 'b'];
    template = 
    `<table>
        ${names.reduce((acc, name) => acc + `<TR><TD>${name}</TD></TR>`, '')}
    </table>
    `
    let div = document.getElementById("container");
    div.innerHTML = template;
```

Comment: `.map().join()` vs. `reduce` with string concat, there's not much in it. `.map().join()` certainly isn't *incorrect*.

Comment: Oh of course not, it's a perfectly correct answer. This is just how I would do it.

Comment: @Shmish I would have marked as good answer also because I didn't think about reduce. But I can only mark one question.